# Hoodie with no hood

Tags: nouns, vocabulary, objects

What is a proper term for for a hoodie like clothing but without a hood. I usually wear this under my coat

Comment: Jacket, probably.

Comment: Jumper? Vest? Sweater?

Comment: Fleece, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoodie) and [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hoodie) define a hoodie as a **sweatshirt** with a hood. From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sweatshirt):

> A loose shirt, usually made of a knit fleece, for athletic wear and now often used as casual apparel.

If it's knitted from wool it can be called "*sweater*", "*jumper*", "*pullover*" or "*jersey*" depending on the region.

Comment: Please don't answer questions that OP could obviously answer for themself with minimal reasonable research.

Comment: I'm wearing one right now, according to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/hoodie) - "1. COUNTABLE NOUN
A hoodie is a type of casual **jacket** with a hood". It is black, but as I am not a hacker in a TV drama I do not have the hood up indoors. My daughter says only 'dweebs' do that. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/hoodie) (Oxford) says "A hooded sweatshirt, jacket, or other top". So any of these could be a 'hoodie without a hood'.